# DX CLI - Cant find Error after moving a folder

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I recently took a folder on my desktop and made it the child of another folder, and now get the following error message when running commands in the CLI:

```
(node:13468) Error Plugin: sfdx-cli: could not find package.json with { type: 'link',
  root: 'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Desktop\\originalFolderThatsNowAChild\\myproject',
  name: 'myproject',
  tag: undefined }
module: @oclif/config@1.15.1
task: loadPlugins
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.62.1-309fe6da17
See more details with DEBUG=*
```

The original folder's new filepath is something like : *C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\newParentFolder\originalFolderThatsNowAChild\myproject*

I tried looking through different JSON files on my system in %localappdata%, but from what I see, it looks like a plugin link is failing because of the changed path.

Can someone point out what is required here? Do I just need to move that folder back to the old path, unlink whatever plugins, then move back to where I want to keep it?